# Install pygame with anaconda on mac

Tags: python, pygame

I was having problems trying to install pygame on a mac where python was installed with anaconda. I searched in SO and no solution worked. But it seems I have worked it out (haven't checked yet throughly ) so I write it here

Comment: The cogsci install did not work for me, but [This link worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61296202/install-pygame-with-anaconda?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, tlatorre does not have a Osx version it seems. So I did this:
`anaconda search -t conda pygame`

and you can see in the reply several places (including tlatorre) with pygame. 
You can see that tlatorre only has linux-64 version. Also quasiben seems to have a Osx version but I tried it and there was some incompatibility with python 3.5*
so I tried CogSci (which seems to have linux windows and osx versions

`conda install -c CogSci pygame=1.9.2`

and it seems that it has been installed. (my apologies if it is not, - I am going to check from now on)