# Install Pygame with Anaconda

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to install pygame on my Mac and get a ton of errors. I'm not 100% sure what this is telling me, except that it's telling me a lot.

Is it saying that Pygame is only compatible with Python 3.5? Because there was another ticket on StackOverflow ([Install pygame with anaconda on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779485/install-pygame-with-anaconda-on-mac)) that said there was a problem with Python 3.5. I'd be surprised if it was incompatible with 3.7.

And if it's not incompatible, what's the problem? Everything I find seems to be quite Windows-centric with its problems and solutions.

```
% conda install -c cogsci pygame
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: - 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                          

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pygame -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*']

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `pip install pygame` instead. The pygame package hosted by `cogsci` hasn't been updated in close to 4 years. That's the reason it still only supports python 2.7 and 3.5

Comment: My experience using pip is that it installs to the “wrong” version of python on my Mac. I need it to install to the installation at /opt/anaconda and it generally goes to the default python that comes with OS X.

Comment: If you're wondering conda evironments contain pip by default. Do a 'conda list | grep pip' in your env to confirm this. Doing `pip install pygame` in the activated environment will use the pip in that env and solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

On OS X with Anaconda I got pygame to work in a terminal with:

> conda activate

> pip install pygame